# Trim output from form to HTML table to not show form information or extra string info

Tags: html, powershell

I have a command:

```
$global:cpus+=$m.Trim("Name")
```

the results are:

```
> Microsoft Windows 10
> Enterprise|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition4
```

I would like to get rid of everything after Enterprise

Another example:

```
$global:domain+=$dmn.Trim()
```

the results are:

```
> Note if on domain:    HostName : XXXXX DomainName : XXXXX.com NodeType :
> Hybrid DhcpScopeName : IsWinsProxy : False
```

I'd like for it just to show the domain name. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try using Regex?

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, split on `|`, then grab only the first part:

```
'Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition4'.Split('|')[0]
```

For the second one, use the `-match` regex operator to capture the domain name, then extract it from the `$Matches` variable:

```
$string = "Note if on domain: HostName : XXXXX DomainName : XXXXX.com NodeType : Hybrid DhcpScopeName : IsWinsProxy : False"

if($string -match 'DomainName : ([\w\.]+)\s+'){
  $domain = $Matches[1]
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  I've tried it already. Either one of the answers.

Comment: Really, even the first one? What do you get when you do `'Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition4'.Split('|')[0]`?

Comment: Thank you everyone, but neither of those solutions worked.

Comment: No, I'm asking, what result do you actually get when running the first statement?

Comment: Not every computer I scan will be a windows 10 enterprise so that command will not work.  It's querying the os in my script.

Comment: function Get-osv {  

 $statusBar.Text=("Processing the request") 
 $computers=$InputBox.lines.Split("`n")  
 $date =Get-Date  
 $ct = "Task Completed @ " + $date  
 $Script:formt.Visible=$true  
 $osver =@()  
 foreach ($computer in $computers)  
 {  
 $Script:formt.text="Working on $computer"  
 $osver +=  Get-ostype $computer   
 $osvr = $osver | ft -AutoSize | Out-String 
 }  
 $outputBox.Appendtext("{0}`n" -f $osvr+"`n $ct"  )   
 
 $global:osversion+=$osver

Comment: @JeffRibbing Can you perhaps [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61776008/edit) to describe what it is you're actually trying to do (including any code you already have and description of any unexpected behavior or error messages you're getting) - will make it much easier to help you out :)